# Proving an operator is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Let $V$ be a complex vector space and $T$ a linear operator on it. Suppose $T T^\ast=6T-8I$. I need to prove $T$ is positive definite.

Doesn't this just follow from the fact $TT^\ast, I$ are positive definite and closure of positive-definite under sums with positive coefficients?

($TT^\ast$ cannot have eigenvalue zero because $\ker T=\ker TT^\ast$ would then yield a contradiction.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v\ne0$ be a vector; then
$$
6v^*Tv=v^*TT^*v+8v^*v>0
$$

Comment: So what I wrote is correct?

Comment: @Exterior Well, $TT^*$ is not necessarily positive definite, but $I$ is.

Comment: $TT^\ast$ is positive semidefinite always (right?), and the equation implies its positive definite because its kernel always coincides with that of $T$ (I wrote this in my question). Right?

Comment: @Exterior $\ker T=\ker T^*T$. However, they have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: Having identical eigenvalues does not get in the way: I'm just saying that sticking some $0\neq v\in \ker T$ into the equation we're given yields a contradiction because $I v=v\neq 0$. This means $T$ and therefore $TT^\ast$ must be invertible.

Comment: @Exterior If $Tv=0$, why should $TT^*v=0$? You're using $TT^*$, as if it were $T^*T$. Be careful.

Comment: Because they have the same kernels, no?

Comment: Ahhh, I noticed now that you wrote $\ker T^\ast T=\ker T$ not $\ker TT^\ast$.. In that case, how can you perform your calculation?

Comment: @Exterior $v^*TT^*v=(T^*v)^*(T^*v)\ge0$.

Comment: Jolly good, thanks